# How to look for a value in a specific pandas data frame column and then store the other values from that row in separate variables

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to automatically send emails based on values found in a csv file that I am reading into a pandas data frame.  I want to figure out how to look for a specific word in a column from the pandas data frame, and when that word appears, I then want to return the other values from that row in separate variables to be used later in the email function (def send_notification).  I have found some methods to return all the variables from a row as one list or string, but I cannot figure out how to store them in separate variables.

The other part that is hanging me up is that I need this to all happen in an iterative fashion.  Since I am trying to use these variables to fill in data in another function (def send_notification) that sends out emails to people, I need the function that stores the data into separate variable to iterate over the data frame, and trigger the email functions (call def check_outlook) for each instance of the trigger word (reasona) in the data frame.  I am not sure how to do this either with pandas.

my csv file will contain something like this:

```
reasons    notes     email
reasona    notea     namea@email.org
reasonb    noteb     nameb@email.org
reasonc    notec     namec@email.org
```

The part of the code that I can't figure out right now is this:

```
def get_email_data():
    for i in dt:
            if i == "reasona":

                # getname = value from column email from row containing key word in dataframe
                # getnotes = will be value from column notes from row containing key word in dataframe.  To be used in email body.
                # get reasons = value from column reasons row containing key word in dataframe. To be used in email body.              
                #Call check_outlook() at the end of this function to trigger email
```

Here is my idea so far for the whole script.  If there is a better way to go about this, any input is greatly appreciate.

```
import win32com.client as win32
import psutil
import os
import subprocess
import pandas as pd

filename = "users\\cmbp\\p4e\\test_rad_reports.csv"
my_csv = pd.read_csv(filename)
dt = pd.read_csv(filename, usecols=['reason', 'notes', 'email'])

def get_email_data():
    for i in dt:
        if i == "reasona":

            # getname = value from row containing key word in dataframe
            # getsubject = value from row containing key word in dataframe
            # getbody = value from row containing key word in dataframe
            #call mak_address() at end of capturing values from pandas dataframe
            #Call check_outlook() at the end of this function to trigger email


        # Drafting and sending email notification to senders. 

        def send_notification():
            outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
            mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
            mail.To = getname
            mail.Subject = "This is a generic subject to all emails"
            mail.body = getreasons + getnotes

            i = 0
            for i

            mail.send

        # Open Outlook.exe. Path may vary according to system config
        # Please check the path to .exe file and update below

        def open_outlook():
            try:
                subprocess.call(['C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16\Outlook.exe'])
                os.system("C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16\Outlook.exe");
            except:
                print("Outlook didn't open successfully")

        # Checking if outlook is already opened. If not, open Outlook.exe and send email

        def check_outlook():
            for item in psutil.pids():
                p = psutil.Process(item)
                if p.name() == "OUTLOOK.EXE":
                    flag = 1
                    break
                else:
                    flag = 0

            if (flag == 1):
                send_notification()
            else:
                open_outlook()
                send_notification()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question you have is that first you don't know how to select rows based on conditions from some columns. I would suggest you to read https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html

The second problem you have is you don't know how to loop over the data frame. Please check https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html

Below is a demo for how things might work.

First, use a mask to select what you want.

```
df[df["reasons"] == "reasona"]
```

Then, use `iterrows` to loop over the selected part.

```
for idx, row in df[df["reasons"] == "reasona"].iterrows():
    doSomething # row will contain the data you need to store to variables
```